# How to get time period of multiple days in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has timestamps of vehicle logs.

**Table look like**

| id | vehicle_type | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | ENTRY | 22-08-01 00:08:47 |
| 2 | 4 | ENTRY | 22-08-01 00:20:17 |
| 3 | 2 | EXIT | 22-08-02 13:48:46 |
| 4 | 2 | EXIT | 22-08-02 14:18:54 |

**I want how many vehicles entered or exited hourly on different days**

| id | hourly_time | entered_count | exit_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22-08-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 22-08-01 01:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 22-08-01 02:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | ................. | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | ................. | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 22-08-02 13:00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | ................. | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 22-08-02 14:00:00 | 0 | 1 |

**I Tried this but didn't get the result what I want. By using below query it's only working for 24hrs (Single Day)**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) as hour, 
       SUM(IF(action = 'ENTER', 1, 0)) as enter_count, 
       SUM(IF(action = 'EXIT', 1, 0)) as exit_count 
FROM vehicle_logs 
WHERE timestamp >= '2022-08-01 00:00:00' 
  AND timestamp <= '2022-08-02 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp);
```

Comment: Rather than extract hour, can you do a substring(timestamp, 1, 11) provided your data look like your sample above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, added Date of the timestamp column in the grouping:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(timestamp), EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp)) AS hourly_time, 
   SUM(IF(action = 'ENTER', 1, 0)) AS enter_count, 
   SUM(IF(action = 'EXIT', 1, 0)) AS exit_count 
FROM vehicle_logs 
WHERE timestamp >= '2022-08-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp <= '2022-08-02 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp);
```